# Get a subgroup in regex

Tags: regex, apache, url, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess, I do some rewriteURL, but I have some problem to get the data.

I have : `RewriteRule    ^forum/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)/?$    index.php?page=forum&category=$1&topic=$3 [NC,L]`

So I can get for example : `index.php?page=forum&category=123&topic=456` with this `URL forum/123-cat/456-topic`

But I would like this regex `^forum/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)(/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+))?/?$`, but the $3 get `456-topic` and not just `456`.

So how to get just `456` ?

Thank you>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3 is the whole thing; the piece you want is $4.

Count by opening parentheses.  `([0-9]+)` is $1, `([a-zA-Z]+)` is $2, `(/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+))` is $3, the `([0-9]+)` inside that is $4, and the `([a-zA-Z]+)` is $5.